# How to play youtube video if playing on own domain

Tags: actionscript-3, video, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using **YouTube** API to play videos uploaded by our team. Our website has also **premium** content, if user has subscribed then they can read premium content.

Here I'm hanging to solve about playing premium videos only if user is subscriber.

Please help me to solve this problem. How can I tell **YouTube** to broadcast/play video if *playing from our own specified domain*.

Or can I add own AS3 script to YouTube video?

Answer (score 0):

Is your premium content also hosted on YouTube? It doesn't look like the YouTube API has that kind of control. You might have to make the video unlisted.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:accessControl